# Calculus 2: Strategy for Integration, Integral of e^(x+e^x)dx

Tags: calculus, integration

How would you find $\int e^{x+e^x}dx$?

I know I need to use $u$-substitution but I tried changing what I use for $u$ but I still could not get the right answer.

If someone could push me in the right direction for what to use for $u$ that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: $e^{x+e^x}$ can be written as $e^x\cdot e^{e^x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** You can write $\int e^{x+e^x}dx$ as $\int e^{e^x}\cdot e^x dx$

Comment: Great. I solved it. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. So now you see the integrand is just $\left(e^{e^x}\right)'$, to point out the solution explicitly for other readers since you have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $u=e^x$ and $du=e^x dx$